# LAN speed is limited in an unexpected asymmetric way

Tags: networking, speedtest

I am paying for download/upload at 300/30 Mbps* (asterisks mean reference to the image below), which occasionally reaches peak of 350/350 Mbps** in [speedtest.net](https://www.speedtest.net/) measurement at the computer A, but only peak 10/350 Mbps*** in speedtest.net measurement at the computer B. Both A and B are on wired LAN, B is behing a pair of [Zyxel PLA5456](https://www.zyxel.com/products_services/2000-Mbps-HomePlug-AV2-Powerline-Pass-Thru-2-Port-Gigabit-Ethernet-Adapter-PLA5456/) adapters which indicate good line quality most of the time.

[image]

Peak upload speed of 350 Mbps at the computer B shows that the line is capable of the speed, but the download there is unable to exceed the peak of 10 Mbps. Have you met such a network condition? What can cause it and how it can be fixed?

(I can observe the similar speed difference on [iperf](https://iperf.fr/) test between computers A and B, where test transfer from B to A shows 30 Mbps, but speed A to B is only 10 Mbps, the same as measured by the speedtest.net.)

Comment: What link rate do the adapters themselves indicate? It seems to be common for Powerline link rates to differ wildly in both directions.

Comment: Have you tried replacing (swapping would do) the cables involved?  That 10mbps is the speed from the stone age, perhaps there's a wiring defect that keeps it from using something higher.

Comment: @grawity – I must explore if there is a way to read the rate details; from the outside, there is only a green LED in 90% of time (manual says "best") which 10% of time degrades to yellow (manual: "better").

Comment: HomePlug AV adapters can be controlled from a computer. If Zyxel's software does not show this information, you can try TrendNet's or TP-Link's; they should still show the current upstream/downstream "link rates" for every adapter pair. Again, the rates aren't necessarily the same in both directions. It's somewhat like Wi-Fi in that regard.

Comment: @grawity – I checked them via computer and the only output they provided was the current data transfer information, not a line speed. But now I am sure it is them who is causing the asymmetry. On the power line long about 20 meters, there is an electricity meter between them (not shown in the picture above), 3 meters from one, 17 meters from another. I would not be surprised if this was causing the asymmetry. I will try to install a socket *behind* that meter so it is not in their way (it is OK, that one is an auxiliary meter, not an official one) and check the change after that.